# OpenGL vertex arrays throw invalid operation error

Tags: java, eclipse, opengl, lwjgl

I've recently started using OpenGL and LWJGL but ever since I tried to mess with/add vertex array objects, I've been getting the same error over and over:

GL_INVALID_OPERATION

I am having a hard time understanding why but I managed to pin down to problem to these methods:

```
glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
vao = glGenVertexArrays();

glBindVertexArray(vao);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(vao);     
glVertexAttribPointer(0, count, GL_FLOAT, false, Float.SIZE * 2, 0);

glBindVertexArray(0);
```

...so basically anything that has to do with vertex arrays throws this error. If anyone could point out what exactly I am doing wrong, that would be great. This is the rest of my code:

```
import static org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11.*;
import static org.lwjgl.opengl.GL15.*;
import static org.lwjgl.opengl.GL20.*;
import static org.lwjgl.opengl.GL30.*;

import java.nio.FloatBuffer;
import java.nio.IntBuffer;

import org.lwjgl.BufferUtils; 

public class Model {

    private int count;
    private int ibo, vao;

    public Model(float[] vertices, int[] indices) {

        count = indices.length;

        glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
        vao = glGenVertexArrays();

        glBindVertexArray(vao);
        glEnableVertexAttribArray(vao);
        glVertexAttribPointer(0, count, GL_FLOAT, false, Float.SIZE * 2, 0);

        glBindVertexArray(0);

        FloatBuffer vBuffer = BufferUtils.createFloatBuffer(vertices.length);
        vBuffer.put(vertices).flip();

        int vbo = glGenBuffers();
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo);
        glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vBuffer, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

        IntBuffer iBuffer = BufferUtils.createIntBuffer(indices.length);
        iBuffer.put(indices).flip();

        ibo = glGenBuffers();
        glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, ibo);
        glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, iBuffer, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
        glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);

    }
    public void draw() {

        glBindVertexArray(vao);
        glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, ibo);

        glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, count, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0);

    }
}
```

Comment: You are mixing fixed-function code with modern OpenGL. Either use `glEnableClientState/glVertexPointer` or `glEnableVertexAttribArray/glVertexAttribPointer`. Which OpenGL version are you targeting?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The parameter of [`glEnableVertexAttribArray`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glEnableVertexAttribArray.xhtml) is the attibute index. This means you have to change your code like this:

```
glBindVertexArray( vao );
glEnableVertexAttribArray( 0 ); // <--- attribute index instead of object name
```

Or you may use [`glEnableVertexArrayAttrib`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glEnableVertexAttribArray.xhtml):

```
glEnableVertexArrayAttrib( vao, 0 );
```

[OpenGL 4.6 core profile specification, 10.3. VERTEX ARRAYS, page 354](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/specs/gl/glspec46.core.pdf):

> An individual generic vertex attribute array in a vertex array object is enabled with the commands
>
> ```
> void EnableVertexAttribArray( uint index );
> void EnableVertexArrayAttrib( uint vaobj, uint index );
> ```

Note,  [`glEnableClientState`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/glEnableClientState.xml) is part of the deprecated fixed function pipeline. If you want to use the fixed function pipeline and `glEnableClientState`, then you have to use [`glVertexPointer`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/glVertexPointer.xml) instead of `glVertexAttribPointer`.